# Redigo multi requests

Tags: go, redis, redigo

I have previously been using this:

```
data, err := redis.Bytes(c.Do("GET", key))
```

to make sure that data returned is a slice of bytes.

However, I now need to add an extra command to the Redis request so I have something like this:

```
c.Send("MULTI")
c.Send("GET", key)
c.Send("EXPIRE", key)
r, err := c.Do("EXEC")
```

but now I can't seem to make the `GET` command return a slice of bytes. I've tried adding `redis.Bytes` like below but no luck.

```
c.Send("MULTI")
redis.Bytes(c.Send("GET", key))
c.Send("EXPIRE", key)
r, err := c.Do("EXEC")
```

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Answer (score 6):

In redis, the `EXEC` command returns an array containing the results of all the commands in the transaction.

redigo provides a `Values` function, which converts an array command reply to a `[]interface{}`.

```
c.Send("MULTI")
c.Send("GET", key)
c.Send("EXPIRE", key)
r, err := redis.Values(c.Do("EXEC"))
```

`r[0]` now has the reply from your `GET` command as a `interface{}`, so you'll need to do a type assertion to get the slice of bytes you're expecting:

```
data := r[0].([]byte)
```

**References**

- func Values: https://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#Values
- Type assertions: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions

Comment: Note that if you are not very familiar with the internals of redis and redigo, it might be safer to also use the built in conversion functions with a nil error value for the secondary conversions.  In this example, that would look like this: `data := redis.Bytes(r[0], nil)`.

Answer (score 4):

`MULTI` is used to send several commands in an atomic way to Redis, by creating a transaction. This is not a pipeline at all.

None of the commands will be actually executed before the `EXEC` call so it is impossible to obtain the value when you call `GET` from within a transaction.

From the docs:

> When a Redis connection is in the context of a MULTI request, all commands will reply with the string QUEUED (sent as a Status Reply from the point of view of the Redis protocol). A queued command is simply scheduled for execution when EXEC is called.

In redigo pipelining is done in a different way:

http://godoc.org/github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis#hdr-Pipelining

What you want to do is something like this (untested):

```
c.Send("GET", key)
c.Send("EXPIRE", key)
c.Flush()
v := redis.Bytes(c.Receive()) // reply from GET
_, err = c.Receive() // reply from EXPIRE
```

Comment: Yeah good point - changed title to something more appropriate.

Comment: I disagree with your remark about modifications. Read consistency is as important as write consistency, and a Redis MULTI/EXEC block can ensure both. There are definitely use cases for which you need to use GET operations in a MULTI/EXEC block.

Comment: @SirDarius It *is* possible to get the results from commands in a transaction. See my answer.

Comment: @wyattisimo I said from **within** a transaction. Your answer obtains the values after the transaction has been executed, just like mine, except in a better way. `Values` is nicer than the `Receive` calls indeed.